# Java queue only printing out last element within for loop.

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, queue

I'm creating a Java array of queues program to represent patients in a doctor array. It lets me add nodes in data structure but when I try to print it out it blows up on me. Here is the method

```
  static boolean [] openflag = new boolean[6];
 static queue [] Clinic = new queue[6]; 
 static String [] Doctor = {"Doctor 1", Doctor 2", "Doctor 3","Doctor 
4","Doctor 5","Doctor 6"};
final static String HEADING = "The clinic moniter of Dylan Rychlik";
static int MAX = 6;
   public static void Listpaitents()
   {
    int queuechoice;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Which doctor would you like to print?");
String InputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Doctor, HEADING, 
 JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 

 queuechoice = Integer.parseInt(InputString);
 if (openflag[queuechoice -1 ] == false){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, that doctor is notaviable");
  }
 else{
   Paitent[] array = Clinic[queuechoice -1].toArray();
   //int size = Clinic[queuechoice -1].getSize();
   int limit = Clinic[queuechoice -1].getSize();
   //System.out.println(limit);
   int x; String out = " Members of the list are: \n";
  // boolean exit = false;
  for(x = 1; x <= limit; x++) {
  out += array[x-1].Print() + "\n";
     // System.out.println(array[x-1] + "\n");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,out);
  }
 }
```

Here is the toarray() method in queue class.

```
public static Paitent[] toArray()
 {
     int x = Length; 
     Paitent[] Array = new Paitent[Length];
     queuenode Current = rear;
     for (x = Length; ((Current != null) && (x >= 1));x--)
     {
         Array[x-1] = new Paitent();
         Array[x-1].update(Current.info);
         Current = Current.next; 

     }
     return Array;

     }
```

And finally, here is the paitent class

```
public class Paitent {
 protected static String  name;
 protected static String telephone;
 protected static int ID;
 //Creates a constructor for a paitent object
 public void paitent()
 {

 name = "";
 telephone = " ";
 ID = 0;

  }
//updates the country object
public void update(Paitent thisThing)
{

name = thisThing.name;
 telephone = thisThing.telephone;
 ID = thisThing.ID;
 }
 //asks for user input for country objects
 public void input(int i)
  {
 String PatronHeading = "Country Data Entry";
 String entername;

 int enterID;
 String enterphone;


 entername = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter the name of 
 paitent  #" + i +": ", PatronHeading, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

 enterphone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter the telephone 
 number for paitent #" + i +": ", PatronHeading, 
 JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
 String PNumberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter the 
 ID for paitent #" + i +": ", PatronHeading, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
 enterID = Integer.parseInt(PNumberString);



 name = entername;

 telephone = enterphone;
 ID = enterID;
 }




//prints the results
public String Print()
 {
 String outputString;
 outputString = "Paitent: " + "-" + name + "\n" + " Telephone number " + 
telephone + " ID " + ID;
return outputString; 
 }
 //gets and sets the PCI in order to sort them
  }
```

Any help? Tried several tactics to fix it and nothing seems to be working. There a lot of code so if you need the full code please let me know!

Comment: `it blows up on me` and `nothing seems to be working` are not good explanations at all. Create a [mcve].

Comment: There are two major things that make this question a horror to read: The formatting of your code is less than optimal, additional you should follow the `java naming convention` as this adds up the the messed up formatting.

Comment: Aslo the code you provided does not compile. The first compilation error will be here:  `{"Doctor 1", Doctor 2", "Doctor 3","Doctor 
4","Doctor 5","Doctor 6"};`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).- Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

A problem with your code is that you are using `static` variables.  This means they can only ever have one value

so change

```
protected static String  name;
protected static String telephone;
protected static int ID;
```

to

```
protected String  name;
protected String telephone;
protected int ID;
```

**edit** and clean up your code